# Timer - hour rolls over at 30 minutes not on the hour does the same every hour

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

On my list of weird things, I have an app with multiple timers, all of the timers show the same behavior which I will attempt to describe clearly here.the app is used to track the session time and pit stop time for an endurance race car if this helps add context.
I have option strict on
if there is any more of the code needed please let me know what is needed, the whole project is a couple of thousand lines, hence the why I have posted what I have here.
thanks in advance Darren

```
  Private Sub TimerCarPit1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerCarPit1.Tick


    'TimerCarPit1.Enabled

    If running1 = True Then
        elapsed1 = DateTime.Now - startTime1
    End If

    Car1TimeLabel2.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                                     CInt(elapsed1.TotalHours),
                                     elapsed1.Minutes,
                                     elapsed1.Seconds,
                                     elapsed1.Milliseconds \ 10)
End Sub
```

and the section that implements it

Public Sub CarPitIN1()

```
    Car1PitInTime = DateTime.Now
    If Not running1 Then
        startTime1 = DateTime.Now
        running1 = True
        TimerCarPit1.Enabled = True


    End If
    'change the color of the Pit in button to dark red and disable it
    With Car1PitInBtn
        .BackColor = Color.DarkRed
        .ForeColor = Color.Black
        .Enabled = False
    End With
    'change stint time from lime to red, stop timer and change pit time from red to green
    Car1StintTimeLabel2.ForeColor = Color.Red
    'Set Grid to first empty line, or add a line
    rowIdx = -1
    If rowIdx = -1 Then
        Grid1.Rows.Add()
        rowIdx = Grid1.Rows.Count - 1
    End If
    For i As Integer = 0 To Grid1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Grid1.Rows(i)
        If row.Cells(8).Value Is Nothing And
                row.Cells(8).Value Is Nothing Then
            rowIdx = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ' Now we can allocate the contents of a TextBox to the second column (column index 1)
    Grid1.Rows(rowIdx).Cells(0).Value = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    Grid1.Rows(rowIdx).Cells(1).Value = AD 'rowIdx 'AA1
    Grid1.Rows(rowIdx).Cells(3).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm.ss")
    Grid1.Rows(rowIdx).Cells(4).Value = Car1PitOutTime.ToString("HH:mm.ss")
    Grid1.Rows(rowIdx).Cells(8).Value = Car1StintTimeLabel2.Text
    Car1TimeLabel2.ForeColor = Color.Lime
    TimerCarStop1.Enabled = False
    If running5 Then
        stopTime5 = DateTime.Now
        elapsed5 = stopTime5 - startTime5
        running5 = False
    End If
    'change pit out button to green and enable it.
    With Car1PitOutBtn
        .BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
        .ForeColor = Color.White
        .Enabled = True
        'AddHandler Car1PitOutBtn.Click, AddressOf Car1Pitout_Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```vb
CInt(elapsed1.TotalHours)
```

`TotalHours` is type `Double` and the `CInt` function will round a `Double` value. That means that anything less than 0.5 will round down to zero and anything from 0.5 up will round to 1. What you need to do is remove the fractional part, because that's accounted for in the other parts. You should use this:

```vb
Math.Floor(elapsed1.TotalHours)
```

You could also use `Math.Truncate` but they amount to the same thing when all values are positive. With a negative value, `Math.Truncate` is equivalent to `Math.Ceiling`.

The `TimeSpan` type has its own `ToString` method that will do the formatting for you though. Instead of this:

```vb
String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
              CInt(elapsed1.TotalHours),
              elapsed1.Minutes,
              elapsed1.Seconds,
              elapsed1.Milliseconds \ 10)
```

do this:

```vb
elapsed1.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss\.ff")
```

You can also use the features of OOP to make things simpler and better here. You can create your own class that incorporates a `Timer` and a `Stopwatch`, starting and stopping both together, and exposes appropriate members, e.g.

```vb
Public Class ElapsedTimer

    Private ReadOnly WithEvents timer As New Timer
    Private ReadOnly stopwatch As New Stopwatch

    Public ReadOnly Property ElapsedTime As TimeSpan
        Get
            Return stopwatch.Elapsed
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Interval As Integer
        Get
            Return timer.Interval
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            timer.Interval = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event Tick As EventHandler

    Public Sub Start()
        timer.Start()
        stopwatch.Start()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Stop()
        timer.Stop()
        stopwatch.Stop()
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTick(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Tick(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick
        OnTick(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

End Class
```

If you want to be able to add an instance to a form in the designer, you simply need to inherit `Component`.

You could then use that class and not have to do any calculations yourself. You can just handle the `Tick` event and get the `ElapsedTime` property. You can then format it as I've shown or even incorporate formatting into that class. You could handle multiple instances' `Tick` event with the same method and use the `sender` to get the `ElapsedTime` value.